# How to have a launchd script create a file with time stamp?

Tags: copy-paste, launchd, automatic-update

I am trying to run a simple launchd script that copies a file from one directory to another when the file changes, but I want to paste it with a unique timestamp so I can version the files. My launchd script looks like follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>change.file.copy</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>cp</string>
        <string>/path/to/folder/sample_file.txt</string>
        <string>/path/to/another_folder/$(gdate +%Y%m%d_%T.%N)_sample_file.txt</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/folder/sample_file.txt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Command works perfectly fine if I run it through the Terminal i.e. if I run:

```
cp /path/to/folder/sample_file.txt /path/to/another_folder/$(gdate +%Y%m%d_%T.%N)_sample_file.txt
```

However, whenever the event triggers it instead created a file with (gdate +%Y%m%d_%T.%N) string in it instead of the actual date i.e. the date operator does not resolve when run through launchd.

I could always create an executable and run that through launchd but I was wondering why the above does not work correctly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. Searching with the right keywords on Google is everything.

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>cp /path/to/folder/sample.txt /path_to_another_folder/$(/usr/local/bin/gdate +%Y%m%d_%T.%N)_sample.txt</string>
</array>
```